# Linearly Independent or Linearly Dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Classify the following statement as true or false. Give a short proof or a counter example 
in support of your answer. 
The functions $f(x)=\cos^2(x)$, $g(x)=\sin^2(x)$, $h(x)=\sec^2(x)$, and $k(x)=\tan^2(x)$ are linearly dependent on the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

By using Wronskian of functions it's too complicated; is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sec^2(x) = \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) + \tan^2(x)$

Comment: A=-1, B=-1, C=-1, D=1 hence Linearly Dependent.

Comment: Yes. [15 characters]

Answer (score 0):

You could always just assume that
$$
\alpha \cos^2(x) + \beta \sin^2(x) + \gamma \tan^2(x) + \delta \sec^2(x) = 0
$$
for all $x$ and then choose specific values of $x$ to try and deduce the values of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$.

However, a better approach would be to use the trigonometric definitions of your four functions: they are side lengths of two right triangles associated to an angle in the unit circle. Apply the Pythagorean theorem to these two triangles!